# How to unview/toggle all the Viewed files on GitHub Pull Request?

Tags: github

I know I can manually go to PR and uncheck Viewed. Is there a shortcut to uncheck on all files in the PR?
[image]

Found some relevant issues on GitHub
https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github/issues/2444

Why I want to do it?
To be able to see the comments and expand the cards which are collapsed because I manually marked viewed.

I tried Option+Click on Mac , didn't work for me.

Answer (score 39):

Don't think the UI currently supports that. It looks like you need to tick, all checkboxes manually. Or come up with a JavaScript to find and click them for you.

Try that in your browser console.

```
document.getElementsByName("viewed").forEach(ch => {if(ch.checked) {ch.click()}})
```

Comment: I added this as a bookmarklet:
`javascript:document.getElementsByName("viewed").forEach(ch => {if(ch.checked) {ch.click()}})`

Comment: since i googled for gitlab and ended up here, gitlab's equivalent is `Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("custom-control-input")).forEach(ch => {if(ch.checked) {ch.click()}})`

Answer (score 4):

Credits to GitHub user [mfulton26](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github/issues/2444#issuecomment-613557336) for the following commands:

| Name | Query/Bookmarklet |
| --- | --- |
| GitHub: View all | `javascript: document.querySelectorAll('.js-reviewed-checkbox').forEach(input => input.checked || input.click());` |
| GitHub: Unview all | `javascript: document.querySelectorAll('.js-reviewed-checkbox').forEach(input => !input.checked || input.click());` |

Answer (score 3):

For people who are using VSCode, you can download the GitHub extension with which you can mark the files as `viewed` or `not viewed` using the checkbox beside the  directory.(Every file in that folder and its sub-folders will be reflect the same)

[image: Github Extension>Pull Requests>The PR you want]

Answer (score 0):

I use a bookmarklet for this task. Here is a version that marks all files as read, if the file-path starts with `some-base-dir`:

```js
javascript:(function() {
  const fileHeaders = document.querySelectorAll('div[class*="file-header"][data-path^="some-base-dir"]');

  fileHeaders.forEach(header => {
    const checkbox = header.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');

    if (checkbox && !checkbox.checked) {
      checkbox.click();
    }
  });
})();
```

To use the bookmarklet, you can create a new bookmark in your browser and paste the above code as the URL. When you visit a page with file headers that match the above selector, simply click the bookmarklet to automatically check all checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use Anton Belev's answer and it worked for some of the smaller PRs but not for a big one I had (1100 files). The javascript failed because it turns out GitHub doesn't like it when you send 1100 requests at once and I got a whole lot of `429` (rate limited) responses ‍♂️.

I've added a sleep and filtered out files that are already unchecked:

```
 const elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByName("viewed")).filter(ch => ch.checked);
 
 for (const element of elements) {
   await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
   element.click();
 }
```